# Zend_Form_Element fails when i addElements

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have been having trouble adding a hidden zend form element.

when i invoke addElements the form fails and prints the following error to the page.
but only when i try and add $formContactID and $formCustomerID.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object in /home/coder123/public_html/wms2/library/Zend/Form.php on line 3291

My code is as follows.

```
  private function buildForm()
 {
  $Description = "";
  $FirstName = "";
  $LastName = "";
  $ContactNumber = "";
  $Fax = "";
  $Position = "";
  $Default = "";
  $custAddressID = "";
  $CustomerID = "";
  $Email = "";
  $ContactID = "";
  if($this->contactDetails != null)
  {
   $Description = $this->contactDetails['Description'];
   $CustomerID = $this->contactDetails['CustomerID'];
   $FirstName = $this->contactDetails['FirstName'];
   $LastName = $this->contactDetails['LastName'];
   $ContactNumber = $this->contactDetails['ContactNumber'];
   $Position = $this->contactDetails['Position'];
   $Fax = $this->contactDetails['Fax'];
   $Email = $this->contactDetails['Email'];
   $Default = $this->contactDetails['Default'];
   $custAddressID = $this->contactDetails['custAddressID'];
   $ContactID = $this->contactDetails['custContactID'];
  }


  $formfirstname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('FirstName');
  $formfirstname->setValue($FirstName)->setLabel('First Name:')->setRequired();

  $formlastname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('LastName');
  $formlastname->setLabel('Last Name:')->setValue($LastName)->setRequired();

  $formPhone = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('ContactNumber');
  $formPhone->setLabel('Phone Number:')->setValue($ContactNumber)->setRequired();

  $formFax = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('FaxNumber');
  $formFax->setLabel('Fax Number:')->setValue($Fax);

  $FormPosition = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Position');
  $FormPosition->setLabel('Contacts Position:')->setValue($Position);

  $FormDescription = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Description');
  $FormDescription->setLabel('Short Description:')->setValue($Description)->setRequired();

  $formEmail = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Email');
  $formEmail->setLabel('Email Address:')->setValue($Email);

  $FormDefault = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('Default');
  $FormDefault->setValue('Default')->setLabel('Set as defualt contact for this business:');

  if($Default == 'Default')
  {
   $FormDefault->setChecked(true);
  }

  $formCustomerID = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('customerID');
  $formCustomerID->setValue($customerID);
  if($this->contactID != null)
  {
   $formContactID = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('ContactID');
   $formContactID->setValue($this->contactID);
  }

// FORM SELECT 
  $formSelectAddress = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('custAddress');
  $pos = 0;
  while($pos < count($this->customerAddressArray))
  {
   $formSelectAddress->addMultiOption($this->customerAddressArray[$pos]['custAddressID'], $this->customerAddressArray[$pos]['Description']);
   $pos++;
  }
  $formSelectAddress->setValue(array($this->contactDetails['custAddressID']));
  $formSelectAddress->setRequired()->setLabel('Default Address For this Contact:');
// END FORM SELECT

  $this->setMethod('post');
  $this->setName('FormCustomerEdit');

  $formSubmit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('ContactSubmit');
  $formSubmit->setLabel('Save Contact');

  $this->setName('CustomerContactForm');
  $this->setMethod('post');


  $this->addElements(array($FormDescription, $formfirstname, $formlastname, 
         $FormPosition, $formPhone, $formFax, $FormDefault, 
         $formEmail, $formSelectAddress, $formContactID, $formCustomerID, $formSubmit));

  $this->addElements(array($formSubmit));

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've already fixed, but just in case.

I was having the same issue and the problem was the name of certain attributes within the form. In your case you have:

```
  if($this->contactID != null){
   $formContactID = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('ContactID');
   $formContactID->setValue($this->contactID);
  }
```

In the moment that you have added $formContactID to the form a new internal attribute has been created for the form object, this being 'ContactID'. So now we have $this->ContactID and $this->contactID.

According to PHP standards this shouldn't be a problem because associative arrays keys and objects attribute names are case sensitive but I just wanted to use your code to illustrate the behaviour of Zend Form.

Revise the rest of the code in your form to see that you are not overriding any Zend Element. Sorry for the guess but since you didn't post all the code for the form file it's a bit more difficult to debug.

Thanks and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on `$this->addElements` when `$formContactID` is missing because of `if($this->contactID != null)` rule.

You can update your code to fix the problem:

```
.....
$this->addElements(array($FormDescription, $formfirstname, $formlastname, 
      $FormPosition, $formPhone, $formFax, $FormDefault, 
      $formEmail, $formSelectAddress, $formCustomerID, $formSubmit));

if(isset($formContactID)) {
  $this->addElements(array($formContactID));
}
......
```

Comment: i can add all elements except of type Zend_Form_Element_Hidden